# RTK Query unable to use mutation on hander in react React (with TS) hook "MultiBrandAPI.myMutation" is called conditionally."

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, rtk-query

So we're migrating to RTK Query. We've been able to work a query without any problems. But Now we're trying to do a POST, and the following problem happens.

This is my function in my component.tsx file:

```
const [postToken] = MultiBrandAPI.useNewPartnerTokenPostMutation();

const handleNavigateToPartner = async(partner: Partner) => {

    const auth = SessionSlice.getInitialState().token;
    try {
        const result = await postToken({
            id: partner.id,
            token: auth
        }).unwrap();
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

And this is my api.ts file:

```
import {Partner} from '@libs/partner';
import {createApi} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

import {BaseQueryWithAuth} from '../redux/rtk-query';

interface PostObject {
    id: string,
    token: string | undefined
}

export default createApi({
    reducerPath: 'multiBrandAPI',
    baseQuery: BaseQueryWithAuth,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        newPartnerTokenPost: builder.mutation<string, PostObject>({
            query: ({id, token}: PostObject) => ({
                url: `u/${id}/token`,
                method: 'POST',
                body: `Authorization ${token}`
            }),
            invalidatesTags: [{type: 'Partners', id: 'LIST'}],
        }),
        getAllPartners: builder.query<Partner[], void>({
            query: () => ({url: 'auth/login'}),
            providesTags: () => {
                return [{type: 'Partners'}];
            }
        }),
    }),
    tagTypes: ['Partners']
});
```

And I'm getting this error on console:

> React Hook
> "MultiBrandAPI.useNewPartnerTokenPostMutation" is called
> conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in
> every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after
> an early return?  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with making a POST - you are just violating the rules of hooks.

You have to call `useNewPartnerTokenPostMutation` in your component function on root level (not in any callbacks) and not inside of `if/else` blocks and before any possible `return` statement. The same would go for any other hook in React.

Comment: Yes, I realize that from the error message. My question in the post is basicaly: "How do I mage a POST with RKT Query and React" I've been reading the doc and even saw some examples and some examples actually did what I described above with no errors.

Comment: I don't know what else than "you call the method `MultiBrandAPI.useNewPartnerTokenPostMutation` in a wrong spot" I should tell you since you are not showing where you call the method.

Comment: This was right! calling it before the return was the trick! Tks for your help!